# Solving for the third angle by taking the cos of two arccos's added together

Tags: trigonometry

Using only trigonometric manipulations, simplify
$$\pi-\left(\arccos\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)+\arccos\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)\right) = \angle c$$ into $$\arccos\left(\frac{A^2+B^2-C^2}{2AB}\right) = \angle c$$

Where A, B, and C are all sides of a triangle.

To be clear, I know that:

$\angle a = \arccos\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)$

$\angle b =\arccos\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)$

$\angle c =\arccos\left(\frac{A^2+B^2-C^2}{2AB}\right)$

$\angle a + \angle b + \angle c = \pi$

However, I was curious about manipulating the actual formula to prove that they are equivalent. I feel like the first step is taking the cosine of both sides... but I get stumped soon enough.

$\cos\left(\pi-\left(\arccos\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)+\arccos\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)\right)\right) = \cos\left(\angle c\right)$

Simplify cos(acos(x)) to x:

$\cos\left(\pi-\left(\arccos\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)+\arccos\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)\right)\right) = \cos\left(\angle c\right)$

take the negative of both to set up a trig identity:

$-\cos\left(\pi-\left(\arccos\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)+\arccos\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)\right)\right) = -\cos\left(\angle c\right)$

convert knowing that cos(x) = -cos($\pi$-x):

$\cos\left(\arccos\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)+\arccos\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)\right) = -\cos\left(\angle c\right)$

cos angle addition:

$\cos\left(\arccos\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)\right)\cos\left(\arccos\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)\right)-\sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)\right)\sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)\right) = -\cos\left(\angle c\right)$

simplify cos(acos(x)) to x:

$\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)-\sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)\right)\sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)\right) = -\cos\left(\angle c\right)$

rearrange:

$\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)+\cos\left(\angle c\right) = \sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)\right)\sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)\right)$

EDITED to fix error: since $(\sin(x))^2+(\cos(x))^2=1$, then $(\sin(\arccos(x))^2+(\cos(\arccos(x))^2=1$, $(\sin(\arccos(x))^2+x^2=1$, $\sin(\arccos(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$:

$\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)+\cos\left(\angle c\right) = \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)^2}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)^2}$

Transform the 1's then simplify and rewrite:

$\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)+\cos\left(\angle c\right)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{2BC}{2BC}\right)^2-\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)^2}\sqrt{\left(\frac{2AC}{2AC}\right)^2-\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)^2}$

$\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)+\cos\left(\angle c\right) =\frac{\sqrt{\left(2BC\right)^2-\left(B^2+C^2-A^2\right)^2}}{2BC}\frac{\sqrt{\left(2AC\right)^2-\left(A^2+C^2-B^2\right)^2}}{2AC}$

$\left(\frac{B^2+C^2-A^2}{2BC}\right)\left(\frac{A^2+C^2-B^2}{2AC}\right)+\cos\left(\angle c\right) =\frac{\sqrt{\left(2BC\right)^2-\left(B^2+C^2-A^2\right)^2}\sqrt{\left(2AC\right)^2-\left(A^2+C^2-B^2\right)^2}}{4ABC^2}$

$\frac{\left(B^2+C^2-A^2\right)\left(A^2+C^2-B^2\right)}{4ABC^2}+\cos\left(\angle c\right) =\frac{\sqrt{\left(2BC\right)^2-\left(B^2+C^2-A^2\right)^2}\sqrt{\left(2AC\right)^2-\left(A^2+C^2-B^2\right)^2}}{4ABC^2}$

$\cos\left(\angle c\right) = \frac{\sqrt{\left(2BC\right)^2-\left(B^2+C^2-A^2\right)^2}\sqrt{\left(2AC\right)^2-\left(A^2+C^2-B^2\right)^2}-\left(B^2+C^2-A^2\right)\left(A^2+C^2-B^2\right)}{4ABC^2}$

$\cos\left(\angle c\right) = \frac{\sqrt{-A^4-B^4-C^4+2A^2B^2+2A^2C^2+2B^2C^2}\sqrt{\left(2AC\right)^2-\left(A^2+C^2-B^2\right)^2}-\left(B^2+C^2-A^2\right)\left(A^2+C^2-B^2\right)}{4ABC^2}$

$\cos\left(\angle c\right) = \frac{\sqrt{-A^4-B^4-C^4+2A^2B^2+2A^2C^2+2B^2C^2}\sqrt{-A^4-B^4-C^4+2A^2B^2+2A^2C^2+2B^2C^2}-\left(B^2+C^2-A^2\right)\left(A^2+C^2-B^2\right)}{4ABC^2}$

$\cos\left(\angle c\right) = \frac{-A^4-B^4-C^4+2A^2B^2+2A^2C^2+2B^2C^2-\left(B^2+C^2-A^2\right)\left(A^2+C^2-B^2\right)}{4ABC^2}$

$\cos\left(\angle c\right) = \frac{-A^4-B^4-C^4+2A^2B^2+2A^2C^2+2B^2C^2+A^4+B^4-C^4-2A^2B^2}{4ABC^2}$

$\cos\left(\angle c\right) = \frac{-2C^4+2A^2C^2+2B^2C^2}{4ABC^2}$

$\cos\left(\angle c\right) = \frac{A^2+B^2-C^2}{2AB}$

$\angle c = \arccos\left(\frac{A^2+B^2-C^2}{2AB}\right)$

Comment: $\sin(\arccos(x)) = \sqrt{1-\cos^2(\arccos(x))} = \sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: Thank you, edited and progressed

Comment: You are almost done. Now factor everything in the square roots: you have a difference of squares, and $u^2-v^2=(u+v)(u-v)$. Factor until you have only  factors of degree $1$ in your variables. Then compare factors from both square roots. Hint: it has a lot to do with [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula), which is to be expected as $S=\frac12bc\sin A$, with usual notation.

Comment: Thank you, the link to Heron's formula was actually very engaging to read. I appreciate that.